# White Space Showing Up on Navigation - SafeView

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Previously, I was using toggling to handle navigation. Now I am switching to useNavigation hooks. From one page, I move to another page like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        if (title == 'h') {
          navigation.navigate('AddFriend');
        }
      }}>
```

When In navigate to the screen, I see an unwanted white space at the bottom, even though the original design did not have this. However, when I click the `Cancel`button, the space disappear, the page formats according to what it should be like and then it navigates back to the original page. Why is it showing the white space? How can I remove it?
[image]

[image]

This is how the code for my AddFriend page looks like:

```
type AddFriendPageProps = {
  toggleShowPage: () => void;
  showAddFriendPage: boolean;
};

export const AddFriendPage: React.FunctionComponent<AddFriendPageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendPage,
}) => {
  const [showAddFriendPhonePage, setShowAddFriendPhonePage] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const toggleAddFriendPhonePage = () => {
    setShowAddFriendPhonePage(showAddFriendPhonePage ? false : true);
  };

  return (
    <Modal 
    visible={showAddFriendPage} 
    animationType="slide" transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View style={styles.searchTopTextContainer}>
              <Text
                style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                >
                Cancel
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchTopMiddleText}>Add Friend</Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}>Done</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button
                  rounded
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => setShowAddFriendPhonePage(true)}>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>Add by Phone Number</Text>
                </Button>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <AddFriendPhonePage
            showAddFriendPhonePage={showAddFriendPhonePage}
            toggleShowPage={toggleAddFriendPhonePage}
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Styles:

```
const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white', //'#2E3331',
    width: '100%',
  },
  searchTopContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#2E3331',
    height: moderateScale(750),
  },
  searchTopTextContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginVertical: moderateScale(15),
    height: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(30),
    paddingRight: moderateScale(30),
  },
  searchCancelDoneText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
    color: 'white',
  },
  searchTopMiddleText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(15),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  searchFieldContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(120),
  },
  button: {
    width: moderateScale(200),
    height: moderateScale(50),
    backgroundColor: '#31C283',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(14, 0.7),
  },
  searchField: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: moderateScale(300, 0.3),
    height: verticalScale(40),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(6),
    borderRadius: verticalScale(10),
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    paddingTop: 250,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  inputText: {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  searchText: {
    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
  },
});
```

If I change the background color the container to red and apply that style on the safeView, it makes the top part (where the time is written) red along with the bottom part which is supposed to match with the other screen. Both come under the safeView thing. How do I separate them?

If I remove the SafeView, the whole screen moves upwards, apart from the Cancel and Done button. The white space increases even more

Answer (score 0):

that white space is added by safeAreaView. if you want the safeAreaView to have the same green background color you have to set the styles on it or it's parent, you currently only have styles on the child View element with the styles.container

I dont understand what you mean by 'how do i separate them'. basically, if you see the red color appear when you apply styles on the safeAreaView then instead of red use the gray/green color on the safeAreaView (that you're already using for the rest of the screen) so that it looks seamless.

Comment: I applied the same styles on SafeAreaView too but it doesn't make a difference. Why is that so?

Comment: maybe put the styles on the parent of the safeAreaView or put a View around the safeAreaView and put styles on that

Comment: Could you see the updated qs with styles pls? I guess safe view includes both, the top and bottom but I only want to fix the bottom such that it matches the rest of the screen while the remaining top part should be white.

Comment: the red was just to test. I meant that if I apply any color in the styling of safe view, it is automatically applied to both ends, the top (where the time is written) and the bottom (white space). I only want to change color on the bottom.

Comment: Currenltly what happens is that when I click on cancel, first the safe view slides to the right and once it's gone, then the screen slides downwards and then navigates back. Is there any way I can skip the safe view sliding and go directly to the whole screen sliding?